# Where do CSS and JavaScript files go in a Maven web app project?

Tags: css, maven, pom.xml

I am switching to use Maven for my Spring web app projects and I am running into a simple issue. I am not sure where to put the CSS and JS files in the new project structure.

**Traditional Web App Structure**

In a traditional Java web app structure (In Eclipse, created as a Dynamic Web Project) I put the CSS, Javascript and Images files under the following structure

```
WebContent
|__css/myStyles.css
|__js/myjs.js
|__images/myImage.gif
|__WEB-INF
```

Then in my jsp if I want to reference a CSS file I do as follows:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/css/myStyles.css">
```

This works fine.

**Maven Web App Structure**

In a Maven project I have put the css files in these locations:

### First Attempt

Under the **webapp** folder at the same level as WEB-INF just like in a traditional dynamic web project. But when I do the following

```
mvn clean tomcat:run
```

I get the following error from the Spring Framework:

```
org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/appname/css/myStyles.css] in DispatcherServlet
```

### Second Attempt

Placed my css folder under **src/main/resources** But when I do the following:

```
mvn clean tomcat:run
```

I get the following error from the Spring Framework:

```
org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/appname/css/myStyles.css] in DispatcherServlet
```

### Third Attempt

Placed my css folder **src/main/resources**

Results: Same as above

I am sure it's something simple but I am stuck, maybe I am overlooking something.

**UPDATE**: Adding pom.xml to see if it can help troubleshoot the issue:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.dariopardo</groupId>
<artifactId>jfreechartdemo</artifactId>
<name>abc</name>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>1.0.0-BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
<properties>
    <java-version>1.6</java-version>
    <org.springframework-version>3.0.6.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
    <org.aspectj-version>1.6.9</org.aspectj-version>
    <org.slf4j-version>1.5.10</org.slf4j-version>
</properties>
<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-maven-release</id>
        <name>Spring Maven Release Repository</name>
        <url>http://maven.springframework.org/release</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-maven-milestone</id>
        <name>Spring Maven Milestone Repository</name>
        <url>http://maven.springframework.org/milestone</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>spring-roo-repository</id>
        <name>Spring Roo Repository</name>
        <url>http://spring-roo-repository.springsource.org/release</url>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <id>JBoss Repo</id>
        <url>https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases</url>
        <name>JBoss Repo</name>
    </repository>
</repositories>
<pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-maven-release</id>
        <name>Spring Maven Release Repository</name>
        <url>http://maven.springframework.org/release</url>
    </pluginRepository>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-maven-milestone</id>
        <name>Spring Maven Milestone Repository</name>
        <url>http://maven.springframework.org/milestone</url>
    </pluginRepository>
    <pluginRepository>
        <id>spring-roo-repository</id>
        <name>Spring Roo Repository</name>
        <url>http://spring-roo-repository.springsource.org/release</url>
    </pluginRepository>
</pluginRepositories>
<dependencies>
    <!-- Spring -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
             </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        <classifier />
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        <classifier />
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-pool</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-pool</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.4</version>
        <classifier />
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
        <classifier />
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-pool</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-pool</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>xerces</groupId>
                <artifactId>xerces</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>xerces</groupId>
                <artifactId>xercesImpl</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
                <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
        <classifier />
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
    </dependency>
            
    <!-- AspectJ -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
        <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
        <version>${org.aspectj-version}</version>
    </dependency>   
    
    <!-- Hibernate -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.4.Final</version>
        <classifier />
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.4.Final</version>
        <classifier />
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>cglib</groupId>
                <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
                <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
        <classifier />
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.0.Final</version>
        <classifier />
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
                <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.GA</version>
        <classifier />
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>cglib</groupId>
        <artifactId>cglib-nodep</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
        <classifier />
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
        <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
        <classifier />
    </dependency>
    
    <!-- Logging -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
        <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.15</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- @Inject -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
        <version>1</version>
    </dependency>
            
    <!-- Servlet -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Test -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.7</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>       
    
    <!-- To bring jfree chart in, iText & Apache POI -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
        <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.2</version>
    </dependency> 
    
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
        <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.5</version>
    </dependency>
    
    <!-- Oracle jdbc drivers -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.oracle</groupId>
        <artifactId>oracle</artifactId>
        <version>10.2.0.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    
</dependencies>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>${java-version}</source>
                <target>${java-version}</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <warName>abc</warName>
            </configuration>                            
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>install</id>
                    <phase>install</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>sources</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>           
    </plugins>
</build>
```

**UPDATE: Adding Web.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

<!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml
                 classpath*:META-INF/spring/applicationContext*.xml                  
    </param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<!-- Processes application requests -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
    
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: Could you show the pom.xml? BTW, you could just compare `.war` file produced with the good one which you built before.

Comment: updated with POM.xml as you suggested. If I do a maven install it generates a war file and it does put the css in there appropriately. But If i do a mvn tomcat:run for rapid development the css files do not seem to make it over the target directory or wherever they need to be so that the application knows about them

Comment: I have changed my command to **mvn clean war:exploded tomcat:run** but that did not work either. How do people run their Maven Java web apps from the IDE without having to create a an actual war and deploying the war to the app server?

Comment: Never used tomcat from maven. I could recommend jetty:run - works great, and I think it should work faster. Also, IDE usually provide web server integration for rapid development, it doesn't require run maven, hence works faster.

Comment: I am doing what you suggest now Right Clicking on the project and doing a **Run As .../ Run On Server** but my css keeps not being applied for some reason. If I have my home.jsp under **webapp/WEB-INF/views** and my css under **webapp/css/styles.css** what should my href path look like? <link rel="stylesheet" href="">

Answer (score 44, accepted):

So if you have your DispatcherServlet configured in a REST like URL pattern such as **/** then css files would go under **src/main/webapp/resources**

Just to clarify this is what I had to do:

1. Make sure that in your **servlet-context.xml** you have as follows:

   ```
   <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />
   ```
2. Create a folder if does not already exist under webapps called **resources**
3. Place your **css** folder along with css files there
4. Reference my css file as follows:

   ```
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/resources/css/960.css"/>
   ```

Comment: I know this is quite old, but if you are using the JSTL core taglib as in:

`<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>`

you can also use:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="<c:url value='/resources/css/dspo-common.css'/>"/> `

Answer (score 16):

I was faced with the same question in a maven project. There seems to be no good answer to my problem. So I did a simple experiment and it worked perfectly.

This is a simple maven project, I have the following directory structure:
(Irrelevant directories are not shown)

```
───src
   └───main
       ├───java
       ├───resources
       └───webapp
           ├───javascript
           │   ├───test.js
           │   ├───example.js
           │   └───jquery-library.js
           ├───WEB-INF
           │    └───web.xml
           └───example.jsp
```

My JSP pages can refer to my javascript libraries simply as

```
<script src=javascript/jquery-library.js></script>
```

There is no need for any special configuration.

Answer (score 4):

> org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound - No mapping found for
>   HTTP request with URI [/appname/css/myStyles.css] in DispatcherServlet

This indicates a configuration problem with your `web.xml`/spring context file.  `DispatcherServlet` should not be processing a request for a `css` resource.

If this does not help troubleshoot the problem, you may want to post relevant snippets of your `web.xml` and spring context file.

Answer (score 0):

From [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44159480/5398328), from @Mario - It depends on the packaging.

If your Maven project is WAR - put it in the `webapp` directory. You can choose to use subfolders within the webapp directory ie: `webapp/css/main.css` or put the file directly within the webapp directory ie: `webapp/main.css`.

If you are using JAR, put in the `resources` directory. As Viratoro@ mentions above, there is some configuration required to map the resources directory.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution I found for this problem is to use Java Configuration

```
@Configuration
 @EnableWebMvc
 public class WebAppConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
     
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        
    registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
    }
}
```