# how to load js file in spring mvc

Tags: javascript, java, spring, spring-mvc

i am trying to load the js file in spring mvc project.

although i done the mapping in servlet file but still the file not getting loaded.

Here is the jsp file

[image]

here is the mapping file

[image]

Even i tried this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/resources/app.js"></script>
```

But things are not working

Please help

Comment: Hope this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7836930/where-do-css-and-javascript-files-go-in-a-maven-web-app-project

Comment: @soorapadman in my project webapp folder was missing , created the resources folder put my js file ... but still things are not working

Comment: did you move resources folder under `Webcontent` folder?

Comment: yeah .. but still no success

Comment: Yours not maven project right?

Comment: yes , its a maven project

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113937/discussion-between-sparsh610-and-soorapadman).