# I can't configure the resources path in Maven

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jakarta-ee

I'm not able to get the correct css path

I have this code on my index.jsp head

```
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="javascript/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="javascript/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="javascript/angular.min.js"></script>
```

Note that if I use this:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

css shows correctly.

Here it's my [project buildpath](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xcUto.png)

Here it's a [similar question not answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24652697/css-not-working-maven-ee)

Comment: And your javascripts works?

Comment: Yes, Javascripts works fine.

Comment: Where your view files are placed? In webapp itself?

Comment: Yes, I left my project buildpath in a picture over the main question. Here it is again: https://i.stack.imgur.com/xcUto.png

Comment: where  your html page is placed?

Comment: It's a jsp file. It's on webapp/WEB-INF/vistas

Comment: Exactly what errors are showing up in your browser's development tools and server logs? You need to be looking through both.

Comment: thanks to your comment @nitind I was able to find the solution. I'm not used to look at my browser's development tools so I found there that my js and css files didn't work. I am migrating a spring-mvc project from jsp to angularjs so working code stop working and I don't even realize. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a duplicated question: I found the solution here.

[Where do CSS and JavaScript files go in a Maven web app project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7836930/where-do-css-and-javascript-files-go-in-a-maven-web-app-project?answertab=votes#tab-top)

but instead doing it on xml as @Viriato said,

> Just to clarify this is what I had to do:
>   Make sure that in your servlet-context.xml you have as follows:
>   `<resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />`, 
>   create a folder if does not already exist under webapps called resources,
>   place your css folder along with css files there,
>   reference my css file as follows:
>   `<link rel="stylesheet" href="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/resources/css/960.css"/>`

I decided to do a java based configuration because I already had my `Config.java` class.
So, I extended my `Config.java` class to the abstract class WebMvcConfigurerAdapter in order to use the method *addResourceHandlers* (which you have to Override if you want to use it)

This is what I had to do:

```
public class Config extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(final ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
    }
...
}
```

Then I had to add the contextpath to my routes:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:8585/electronicaDonPepe/resources/js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:8585/electronicaDonPepe/resources/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script> 

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://localhost:8585/electronicaDonPepe/resources/js/angular.min.js"></script> 

<link href="http://localhost:8585/electronicaDonPepe/resources/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

If you don't know your context path you can use `Scriptlets` like this:

```
<%= request.getContextPath() %>
```

As an example, the code for bootstrap.min.css will be:

```
   <link href="<%= request.getContextPath() %>/resources/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

If you want to know more about scriptlets you can read this: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/tutorial/doc/bnaou.html

I'm planning to work with `Angular` so hardcoded routes works for me by now, **I don't encourage to do this** because this is a bad practice. The user shouldn't be able to see your resources routes and mess around with them.

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

you can use this cdn for bootstrap

```
<!-- You can use this link for bootstrap cdn  -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-rHyoN1iRsVXV4nD0JutlnGaslCJuC7uwjduW9SVrLvRYooPp2bWYgmgJQIXwl/Sp" crossorigin="anonymous">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
```

Comment: Yes, I know. I'm trying to use the downloaded bootstrap.min.css file. Imagine that I have to show this project without an internet connection.

Answer (score 0):

use

```
`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">`
```

it works fine

**test and verified**

here is a check on below,here I added the container class (**which is a bootstrap class)**  => padding of 15px is added on both left and right.

```css
#test{
  background:red;
  height:200px;
  }
```

```html
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  </head>
<body>
<ul class="list-group">this is  ul tag
  <li class="list-group-item">i didn't applied list-style:none</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">i didn't applied any style to ul,li tags</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">but it's working</li>
  <li class="list-group-item">which meants <strong>bootstrap</strong> is working</li>
</ul>
<div class="container">
  <div id="test"></div>
</div>
  </body>
```

Comment: Hi, linking to a server works fine but that's not what i'm looking for. I'm trying to link the css file from my computer.

Answer (score 0):

Use type attribute in your link tag :

```
<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Comment: I already tried this but it's the same response. It doesn't work.