# CSS file not able to locate in J2EE Dynamic Web Project

Tags: java, html, css

I have the following file structure for my Dynamic Web Project

```
src
 +---main
 |   +---java
 |       +---all the java files under proper packages
 +---resources
 |   +---css
 |       +---index.css
 +---webapp
     +---WEB-INF
     |   +---web.xml
     +---index.html
```

Now, I have specified `index.html` as the welcome file in `web.xml`. But when I'm specifying link to CSS file `index.css` in `index.html`, it's not able to find the file.

I'm referring to the CSS file in the following way

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
```

Checkout this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iAygM.jpg) for the structure of all the web files that are deployed in web browser.

**Edit:** I also have tried referring to CSS file like this

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/css/index.css">
```

But still not working.

Note : I haven't used anything related to spring yet. It's just a simple Web application with a html and css file.

Comment: Did you try putting the css file in `webapp/css` folder?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where do CSS and JavaScript files go in a Maven web app project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7836930/where-do-css-and-javascript-files-go-in-a-maven-web-app-project)